# Where & How is user group information stored in Ubuntu?

Tags: password, group, useradd

Two places possible: [/etc/group](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcgroup-file/) and [/etc/passwd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/passwd.5.html).

If I use command: `adduser [username] [groupname]`, then the user would be added to the group, and the file `/etc/group` would then be updated.

However, the file `/etc/passwd` is not updated. if I check which group I belongs to, via `groups` command, I can only see groups stated in `passwd` file.. therefore, the user is not added to the group base on this result.

---

Mirror Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31530362/where-how-is-user-group-information-stored-in-ubuntu. (I'll remove one of them after I got the answer)

I'm confused.

1. What's the meaning of storying group info into `/etc/passwd`, and `/etc/group` respectively?
2. Why `adduser` only update the `group` file?
3. How to add group to the `passwd` file via command?
4. Why does `groups` return group info from `passwd` file, but not `group` file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The list of groups a user belongs to is stored in `/etc/group` When you add a user to group `/etc/group` is updated. The `/etc/passwd` file doesn't tell you which users belong to which groups. It only has the group id of the user's default group. The `groups` command returns info from `/etc/group`

Comment: Why do we have `default group` thing?

Comment: The default group is used to determine group ownership of files/directories created by a user. For example, if I belong to three groups and create a new file, the group that the file is owned by is my default group (as taken from `/etc/password`).

Answer (score 0):

/etc/group lists all the groups, when you issue the command:

```
groups
```

It shows you all the groups you belong to, Which is gotten from /etc/group

/etc/passwd shows all the information for a user, stuff like username, userid, default groupid,  home directory, and your default shell. The user is added to this file once you create then via `adduser`.

Another interesting command is:

```
id
```

This will list all the real and effective user and group id's.